# Using superclass in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa

I have 2 tables - ClientAccount and BankAccount. Operations allowed are e.g. "buy" - that means transfer money from bank account to client account; and "transfer" - that means transfer money between two client accounts. I want to log both these events. To do so, I created a table Log, with sender and recipient fields, and now I need to define a proper way to define relationships between these 3 tables.

Firstly I decided to make recipient and sender as of ClientAccount type but in this case I cannot add info about "buy" operation (because sender in that case would be of BankAccount type).

Is there any way to create a superclass Account, which will be extended both by BankAccount and ClientAccount so I can use a simple Account type in Log table? What relationships do I have to define then?

Answer (score 0):

You need `Account` parent entity and children `ClientAccount` and `BankAccount`. Then, you would be able to save account-account operation in the log.

It's up to you how to persist it in the database. Different ways are described here:
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance